# Why my code coverage is zero percent even unit test all passed?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have created a project with just one method and I have written a unit test on it and the unit test passed locally. But not sure why after running sonar cloud scanner, it shows zero percent coverage.

[image]

[image]

This is the test class

```
public class DataStructureTest
{
    private readonly DataStructure ds;

    public DataStructureTest()
    {
        ds = new DataStructure();
    }

    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(LongestString_Return_Longest_String_ShouldPass_Data))]
    public void LongestString_Return_Longest_String_ShouldPass(string input, string expect)
    {
        // Act
        var actual = ds.LongestString(input);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expect, actual);
    }

    public static TheoryData<string, string> LongestString_Return_Longest_String_ShouldPass_Data()
    {
        return new TheoryData<string, string>
        {
            { "Hello John", "Hello" },
            { "Hi John and Mandy", "Mandy" }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with code-coverage testing via CI tools or static code analysis tools like Sonarqube, is that `unless the information is captured` (particularly during CI), you are going to get `0%`.   I had this back in the day with **TeamCity** and is still relevant for say **DevOps**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful about what these softwares mean when they use some term. For example, SonarQube has following article: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-and-code-coverage/4725

FAQ has this as first question:

> Q: After migrating from 5.6 to 6.7 my coverage shows 0%, why is that ?
> R: Since SonarQube 6.2 and the implementation of the MMF-345 565, if no coverage information is found the coverage is then set to zero by default.

I think your case may come under this.